# Having Camera Calibration matrix how to extract distortion?

Tags: opencv, distortion

I have a camera calibration matrix that looks like this:

```
  8471.595573      0.000000   1251.025035 
     0.000000   8438.951911    330.567798 
     0.000000      0.000000      1.000000
```

I want to undistort the image with width: 1920, height: 1080
[image]

Yet when I call:

```
undistort(frame, out_frame, cam_k, noArray(), noArray());
imwrite("in.png", frame);
imwrite("out.png", out_frame);
```

there is no difference between frame and out_frame.

Do I do something wrong? Does OpenCV require something more than Camera Calibration matrix to undistort image? If yes Having a Camera Calibration matrix how to extract distortion?

Comment: You're using empty distortion parameters... So you won't undistort anything

Comment: How one can compute them?

Comment: This is called [camera calibration](http://vhosts.eecs.umich.edu/vision//teaching/EECS442_2012/lectures/lecture4.pdf). For OpenCV doc: https://docs.opencv.org/